# transfer coordinate to dialog in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to scale the imported picture in my program to real size. To realize it, I need to select two points from mainwindow and input real length between these two points. Based on the ratio between length measured from mainwindow and my input real length, I can scale the picture to its real size.
Now, I have designed a dialog. What I want to do is when the button "Select point" is clicked, the dialog disappears. After I click on mainwindow, the dialog appears again, meanwhile the coordinate where I click is sent to corresponding spinbox. I don't know how to send the coordinate to my dialog.

Here is my current code for this dialog

```
#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
    class QWDialogBackgroundScale;
}

class QWDialogBackgroundScale : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT


public:
    explicit QWDialogBackgroundScale(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~QWDialogBackgroundScale();

    bool selecting_first_point = false;
    bool selecting_second_point = true;

    float start_x();
    float start_y();
    float end_x();
    float end_y();
    float length();

private slots:
    void on_btnSelectFirstPoint_clicked();
    void on_btnSelectSecondPoint_clicked();
    void on_btnOK_clicked();
    void on_btnCancel_clicked();


private:
    Ui::QWDialogBackgroundScale *ui;
};
```

[image: backgroundscale dialog]

Comment: Extend your dialog with an appropriate method and call this in the mouse event processing of main window. This call might happen just before the main window shows dialog again.

Comment: @Scheff I have solved it. thanks